# retrieve RLMObject where value exist in RLMArray<RLMString*> in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

i create Stock_RLM : RLMObject and Stock_RLM have RLMArray of RLMString.
i want filer RLMObject using RLMArray's Value. It's Possible?

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
    @interface Stock_RLM : RLMObject
    @property NSString *_id;
    @property NSString  *code;
    @property NSString *name;
    @property NSString  *full_name;
    @property NSString *type;
    @property RLMArray<RLMString> *stock_sectors;

@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Stock_RLM)
```

My RLMObject is : -

```
Stock_RLM {
    _id = 5b60554726f2fe334cad881d;
    code = GRASIM;
    name = GRASIM;
    full_name = Grasim Industries Limited;
    type = NSE;
    stock_sectors = RLMArray<string> <0x1c4114d00> (
        [0] 5b6046d1f1e8972b9cebd584,
        [1] 5b6046d1f1e8972b9cebd586,
        [2] 5b6046d1f1e8972b9cebd587,
        [3] 5b6046d1f1e8972b9cebd588,
        [4] 5b6046d1f1e8972b9cebd59a,
        [5] 5b6046d1f1e8972b9cebd5c1
    );
}
```

**i Want to filter '5b6046d1f1e8972b9cebd584'exist in RLMArray in RLMObject or Not.**

Answer (score -1):

in your **.h

```
@interface TESTClass:NSObject
@property NSString *_id;
@property NSString *_code;
@property NSString *_name;
@property NSArray *theStrArr;
@end
```

in your **.m

```
@implementation TESTClass
@end
```

in somewhere you test

```
    TESTClass *obje1 = [[TESTClass alloc] init];
    TESTClass *obje2 = [[TESTClass alloc] init];
    TESTClass *obje3 = [[TESTClass alloc] init];
    obje1.theStrArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"11",@"22",@"33",nil];
    obje2.theStrArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"44",@"55",@"66",nil];
    obje3.theStrArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"77",@"88",@"99",nil];
    NSArray *totalArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obje1,obje2,obje3, nil];
    NSString *testStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"22"];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theStrArr CONTAINS %@",testStr];
    NSArray *resultArr = [totalArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    CLog(@"the result arr %@",resultArr);
```

Comment: it's dynamic data so it's not fair.

Comment: NSPredicate is the method you should use. not concern the data.

Comment: @iMark  RLMArray not for NSArray.